Mean value theorem in hypersurface.
I am curious if there are any generalizations of mean value theorem in higher dimensions. More precisely:
"Generalization":
Let $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a regular hypersurface given by a $C^1$-parametrization $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. (i.e. its Jacobian matrix has full rank pointwisely.)
Let $P,Q$ be two points on $M$, does there always exists some normal vector $\vec{n}$ at some point $R\in M$, such that:
$$ \vec{n}\perp \vec{PQ}$$
My Thoughts:

When $n=1$, this is just the mean value theorem.

When $M$ can be written as $F^{-1}(0)$, where $F\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^{n+1},\mathbb{R})$, then the conclusion also follows from the mean value theorem.


3 (Added). It seems that we cannot use mean value theorem directly:
suppose $\varphi(M)=P,\varphi(N)=Q$, with $M,N\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, if we componentwisely apply mean value theorem we will get:
$$ \vec{PQ}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_1}|_{R_1} & \dots & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_n}|_{R_1}\\
\vdots &  &\vdots \\
\frac{\partial F_{n+1}}{\partial u_1}|_{R_{n+1}} & \dots & \frac{\partial F_{n+1}}{\partial u_n}|_{R_{n+1}}\\\end{pmatrix} \cdot \vec{MN}$$
where $R_1,\dots,R_{n+1}$ may be different points on the line segment $\overline{MN}$, therefore the columns of the matrix may have nothing to do with the tangent vectors.
In general, can we prove it or disprove it?
Welcome to any comments, ideas or references (if any). Thanks!
Edit: Some further thoughts: e.g. for the case $n=2$, if we can show that there exists a plane curve on the surface connecting $P,Q$, then we can apply the case $n=1$ and we are done. But how can we show this? (Maybe related to the theory of tranversality?)

It seems to me that a higher dimensional version of the mean value theorem should  involve a hyperplane tangent to the graph and not a line. Maybe you could try to formulate it that way?

Thanks to my classmate Huajun Bian, this generalization is proven to be wrong. Here is a counterexample.
Let $n=2$, $\varphi:(u,v)\mapsto (X(u,v),Y(u,v),Z(u,v))$. WLOG, suppose $P=(0,0,0), Q=(0,0,1)$. The condition $\vec{n}\perp \vec{PQ}$ is equivalent to that $\vec{PQ}$ lies in the tangent space of some point, which is equivalent to:
$$ 0=\begin{vmatrix} X_u &X_v &0\\
 Y_u & Y_v & 0\\
 Z_u & Z_v & 1 \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} X_u &X_v \\
 Y_u & Y_v  \end{vmatrix} $$
for some point $R\in M$. However, this is not true in general. Consider:
$$\begin{aligned}
\varphi: [0,1]^2&\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3\\
(u,v)&\mapsto (e^{u-v} \cos\pi(u+v)-1, e^{u-v} \sin \pi(u+v),u)
\end{aligned} $$
Then $\varphi(0,0)=(0,0,0), \varphi(1,1)=(0,0,1)$, but
$$\begin{aligned}
\begin{vmatrix} X_u &X_v \\
 Y_u & Y_v  \end{vmatrix}&= \begin{vmatrix} e^{u-v}(\cos \pi(u+v)-\pi \sin\pi(u+v)) & e^{u-v}(-\cos\pi(u+v)-\pi \sin\pi(u+v))\\
e^{u-v}(\sin \pi(u+v)+\pi \cos\pi(u+v)) & e^{u-v}(-\sin\pi(u+v)+\pi\cos\pi(u+v)) \end{vmatrix}\\
&=2e^{2(u-v)}\pi\neq 0 
\end{aligned} $$

@TedShifrin Thank you professor, I made a mistake. Now it's ok.
